# Identity Server with Azure AD aand custom login page

Tags: identityserver4

I'd like to setup an identity server that connects to azure ad but I'd like to use a custom login page in identity server, is this possible?

I know Azure AD allows custom branding but it doesn't allow the type of customization we need.

Comment: What is the exact customization you need? IdentityServer4 can federate to Azure AD, but the Azure AD login page would still be used.
An alternative could be to use the ResourceOwner flow, create a custom login page, and forward the credentials to Azure AD, but there are significant security implications of this approach.

Comment: We'd like to add some custom links to the login screen, it doesn't seem like that's possible with the customized branding options that azure ad premium offers

Answer (score 2):

While Azure AD does not directly support UI customization, Azure AD B2C does. Refer to this Microsoft Doc as a guide to customizing the UI for Azure AD B2C:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-customize-ui-custom#upload-the-ui-customization-pack-sample-files

As described in the Microsoft Doc, the simplest template is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your page content’s tile!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My custom header!</h1>
    <div id="api"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only requirement is the 'anchor element' of `<div id="api"></api>` contained in the top level of `<body>`. All else is customizeable. You could even use cshtml files and razor templating or some other dynamic templating engine if dynamic pages are required.

In addition, Azure AD B2C is still an OAuth2 provider, so federating IdentityServer4 up to it is still possible with this approach.